# Bearer Token Auth not working with Swashbuckle and ASPNetZero / ABP

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to include security header information in my Swagger specifications and SwaggerUI, as I would like 3rd party systems to easily consume my API, as well as to be able to use CodeGen tools like Swagger CodeGen and NSwag to generate client libraries from it.

I am using Swashbuckle / SwaggerGen to generate the documentation automatically during runtime.
My API makes use of bearer token authentication, and I want my SwaggerDocs to reflect my authentication scheme.  I would also be able to see the required security header information in my SwaggerDocs, and have the ability for clients to test out authentication via SwaggerUI when trying out API calls.

[image]

However, I have been unable to successfully have my security header information appear on my own solution.

This is what my I currently see when I view my SwaggerDocs through my local SwaggerUI during debugging:
[image]

Note that the generated OAS3 markup is correctly rendered when running it through https://editor.swagger.io/

Here is the actual markup that gets produced by Swashbuckle / SwaggerGen:

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "MyDemo Host API v1",
        "version": "v1"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/api/services/app/Tenant/CreateTenant": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "Tenant"
                ],
                "operationId": "ApiServicesAppTenantCreatetenantPost",
                "requestBody": {
                    "content": {
                        "application/json-patch+json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "allOf": [
                                    {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateTenantInput"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "allOf": [
                                    {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateTenantInput"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "text/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "allOf": [
                                    {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateTenantInput"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "application/*+json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "allOf": [
                                    {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateTenantInput"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "content": {
                            "text/plain": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SwaggerDocResponseWrapper"
                                }
                            },
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SwaggerDocResponseWrapper"
                                }
                            },
                            "text/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SwaggerDocResponseWrapper"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "bearer": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "CreateTenantInput": {
                "required": [
                    "adminEmailAddress",
                    "name",
                    "tenancyName"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "tenancyName": {
                        "maxLength": 64,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}$",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "maxLength": 128,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "adminEmailAddress": {
                        "maxLength": 256,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "email"
                    },
                    "adminPassword": {
                        "maxLength": 128,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "connectionString": {
                        "maxLength": 1024,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "shouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "sendActivationEmail": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "editionId": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "isActive": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "subscriptionEndDateUtc": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "isInTrialPeriod": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "onSellingPartnerId": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "onSellingPartner": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/OnSellingPartnerDto"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactPersonFirstName": {
                        "maxLength": 32,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactPersonLastName": {
                        "maxLength": 32,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactNumber": {
                        "maxLength": 24,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactEmail": {
                        "maxLength": 256,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "taxNumber": {
                        "maxLength": 24,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "registeredName": {
                        "maxLength": 256,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "tenantBillingAddress": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TenantBillingAddressInput"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nullable": true
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "ValidationError": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "members": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "nullable": true
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "SwaggerDocResponseWrapper": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "result": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "targetUrl": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "success": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "error": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResponseError"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "unauthorizedRequest": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "__Abp": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "OnSellingPartnerDto": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "isActive": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "registeredName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "taxNumber": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactNumber": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactPersonFirstName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactPersonLastName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "contactEmail": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "TenantBillingAddressInput": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "streetAddress": {
                        "maxLength": 256,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "region": {
                        "maxLength": 64,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "maxLength": 64,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "countryId": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "regionCode": {
                        "maxLength": 6,
                        "minLength": 0,
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "ResponseError": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "code": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "details": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "validationErrors": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ValidationError"
                        },
                        "nullable": true
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        },
        "securitySchemes": {
            "bearer": {
                "type": "http",
                "description": "Specify the authorization token.",
                "scheme": "bearer",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT"
            }
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

Environment:

- AspNetZero Core MVC & JQuery v10.3.0 (.Net 5)
- Abp (6.2.0)
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (5.6.3) & Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.NewtonSoft (6.1.4)

The following code gets called from the `ConfiguredServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
        public override void InstallServices(IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment, IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (WebConsts.SwaggerUiEnabled)
            {
                //Swagger - Enable this line and the related lines in Configure method to enable swagger UI
                services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerDoc(ApiNames.HostApiv1, new OpenApiInfo { Title = ApiTitles.HostApiv1, Version = "v1" });
                    options.SwaggerDoc(ApiNames.PartnerApiv1, new OpenApiInfo { Title = ApiTitles.PartnerApiv1, Version = "v1" });
                    options.SwaggerDoc(ApiNames.TenantApiv1, new OpenApiInfo { Title = ApiTitles.TenantApiv1, Version = "v1" });

                    OpenApiSecurityScheme securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                    {
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        BearerFormat = "JWT",
                        Scheme = "bearer",
                        Description = "Specify the authorization token.",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    };

                    OpenApiSecurityRequirement securityRequirements = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                    {
                        {securityDefinition, new string[] { }},
                    };

                    options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearer", securityDefinition);
                    // Make sure swagger UI requires a Bearer token to be specified
                    options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirements);

                    options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
                    {
                        if (!apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.IsControllerAction())
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo);

                        var actionDocs = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerDocAttribute>()
                            .SelectMany(a => a.IncludeInDocuments);

                        var controllerDocs = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerDocAttribute>()
                            .SelectMany(a => a.IncludeInDocuments);

                        switch (docName)
                        {
                            case ApiNames.HostApiv1:
                                return apiDesc.GroupName == null ||
                                       actionDocs.Contains(ApiNames.HostApiv1) ||
                                       controllerDocs.Contains(ApiNames.HostApiv1);
                            case ApiNames.PartnerApiv1:
                                return apiDesc.GroupName == null ||
                                       actionDocs.Contains(ApiNames.PartnerApiv1) ||
                                       controllerDocs.Contains(ApiNames.PartnerApiv1);
                            case ApiNames.TenantApiv1:
                                return apiDesc.GroupName == null ||
                                       actionDocs.Contains(ApiNames.TenantApiv1) ||
                                       controllerDocs.Contains(ApiNames.TenantApiv1);
                            default:
                                return true;
                        }
                    });

                    options.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
                    options.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();
                    options.OrderActionsBy((apiDesc) => $"{apiDesc.RelativePath}");
                    options.ParameterFilter<SwaggerEnumParameterFilter>();
                    options.SchemaFilter<SwaggerEnumSchemaFilter>();
                    options.OperationFilter<SwaggerOperationIdFilter>();
                    options.OperationFilter<SwaggerOperationFilter>();
                    options.CustomDefaultSchemaIdSelector();
                    options.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();


                    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

                }).AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
            }
        }
```

More background information:
I am generating my API documentation into separate SwaggerDocs, for the different types of consumers of my API (Internal / Host applications; Partner applications; Normal tenant / client applications).  TI decorate my ApplicationServices (which are dynamically served up as REST-like services during runtime by ABP/AspNetZero) with `SwaggerDocsAttribute`, which is used to delineate to which one-or-more Swagger docs should include it in its documentation.

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class SwaggerDocAttribute: Attribute
    {
        public SwaggerDocAttribute(params string[] includeInDocuments)
        {
            IncludeInDocuments = includeInDocuments;
        }

        public string[] IncludeInDocuments { get; }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
    [SwaggerDoc(ApiNames.HostApiv1, ApiNames.PartnerApiv1, ApiNames.TenantApiv1)]
    public class SystemStatusAppService: MyDemoAppServiceBase, ISystemStatusAppService
    {
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(SwaggerDocResponseWrapper))]
        public async Task Ping()
        {
            //Do nothing - will return status code 200
        }

        [AbpAuthorize()]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(SwaggerDocResponseWrapper))]
        public async Task PingWithAuth()
        {
            //Do nothing - will return status code 200
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually scratch my previous comment, the generated spec does have some errors, which you can see if you paste it into https://editor.swagger.io. Specifically, the security scheme name mismatch - the scheme in the `components/securitySchemes` section is named `jwt_auth` but operations refer to `security: - bearer: []`. The name in both places must be the same (either "jwt_auth" or "bearer"). I think changing the name in `options.AddSecurityDefinition("jwt_auth", securityDefinition);` to `"bearer"` should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you - I'm going to try it.  Still new to this and finding up-to-date  and accurate documentation has been a challenge!

Comment: @Helen I have made the suggested changes and yes, the OpenApi specification seems to be generated correctly now and on editor.swagger.io it now renders correctly.... I am able to see the "Authorize" button and prompt.  However, this is still not being rendered correctly on my local implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a reference to your definition in your requirement.

```cs
OpenApiSecurityScheme securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    Scheme = "bearer",
    Description = "Specify the authorization token.",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
};

options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityDefinition);

OpenApiSecurityRequirement securityRequirements = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" }
        },
        new string[] {}
    }
};

options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirements);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @CShark I've updated the code sample and can confirm that this works for me.